# How i can find all unique sets of positions of elements in matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to solve the following problem for a 5×5 matrix, but to explain I will use an example with a 3×3 matrix:

```
A = { { 1, 3, 2 }
     ,{ 3, 2, 3 } 
     ,{ 0, 4, 5 } };
```

I need to find all distinct sets of 3 (because the matrix is 3x3)  positions sharing no row or column with the others, compute the sum of elements of A for each set of positions, and print the minimum of these sums.

```
Position = (0,0),(1,1),(2,2) sum = 1+2+5 = 8
           (0,0),(1,2),(2,1) sum = 1+3+4 = 8
           (0,1),(1,0),(2,2) sum = 3+3+5 = 11
           (0,1),(1,2),(2,0) sum = 3+3+0 = 6
           (2,0),(1,1),(0,2) sum = 0+2+2 = 4
           .       
           .       
           .
```

(I think you understood the main principle).

So the output must include:   (2,0),(1,1),(0,2)  minimal sum = 4

Remember:  I actually need to do it for a 5×5 matrix.

Comment: So you want to consider diagonals too, and diagonals that "wrap". When you iterate, take the iterators modulo 3 (or 5) to index.

Comment: Can you show us what goes wrong with your attempt? How did you try implementing it?

Comment: I think OP is asking for an algorithm that generates all possible combinations of index-pair triplets s.t. all row indices and column indices are not equal.

Comment: I think your example solution is wrong, (0,1) == 3, not 1. (0,0) is 1. The minimal sum is (2,0),(1,1),(0,2) =2+2+0=4

Comment: @mch yes you're right thank you

Comment: @Fearless_Wolf:  I made some edits to your question in a way that I hope clarifies it and makes it more likely that other people who have similar questions and search SO will find it. Please take a look and re-edit appropriately if I've inadvertently altered your meaning or intent (in which case, I apologize for the misunderstanding and I'd probably want to revisit my answer below). I felt pretty sure based on the discussion here and the other answer that my understanding was accurate.

Comment: @ThomasKammeyer  i think, i did it thank you , for your edits

Answer (score 0):

A functional, albeit naive, way to do this is to use 6 for-loops (5 nested). Loop from 0 to 2 with the top loop storing its iteration # in an int (called firstRow for example). Similarly the second loop will store firstCol. The third loop will be used to store secondRow so you'll need to `continue` if `secondRow == firstRow`. For the last two loops you'll need to check against the indeces for the other two. In the innermost nested loop, call your findSum function with the 3 coordinate pairs.

```
testCoords(*arr1, *arr2, *arr3)
{
    #get the sum
}

#algorithm defined for n = 3 
mySearch(n)
{
    int coord1[2], coord2[2], coord3[2]; #assume 3by3
    int minSum = n * MAX_VAL, obsSum;

    for (int r1 = 0; r1 < n; r1++)
    {
        coord1[0] = r1;

        for (int c1 = 0; c1 < n; c1++)
        {
            coord1[1] = c1;

            for (int r2 = 0; r2 < n; r2++)
            {
                if (r1 != r2)
                {
                    coord2[0] = r2;

                    for (int c2 = 0; c2 < n; c2++)
                    {
                        if (c1 != c2)
                        {
                            coord2[1] = c2;

                            for (int r3 = 0; r3 < n; r3++)
                            {
                                if (r1 != r3 && r2 != r3)
                                {
                                    coord3[0] = r3;

                                    for (int c3 = 0; c3 < n; c3++)
                                    {
                                        coord3[1] = c3;

                                        obsSum = testCoords(coord1, coord2, coord3);
                                        if (obsSum < minSum)
                                        {

                                            minSum = obsSum;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This will be fine for small arrays such as n=3 or n=5, but the number of iterations quickly gets ridiculous as its n^(n*2). For example, even with 5x5 matrix you'll do 10 million iterations (not too mention a long winded algorithm). A more dynamic algorithm or perhaps a tree implementation is probably a good fit here. For example, a recursive approach could find one index pair (which eliminates a row and column), then calls itself with the resultant (n-1)*(n-1) 2d array -- as so:

```
int minSum = n * MAX_VAL;

coordSearch(int **matrix, n)
{
    int thisCoord[2];

    if (n == 1)
    {
        return matrix[0][0];
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            thisCoord[0] = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                thisCoord[1] = j;


                ##need to update the matrix s.t. row represented by i is removed and col represented by j is removed
                ##ill leave that up to you -- assume its called updatedMatrix

                updatedMatrix = reduce(matrix, i, j);

                return matrix[thisCoord[0], thisCoord[1]] + coordSearch(updatedMatrix, n-1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
        #have some 2d structure that is n * n

        int minSum = n * MAX_VAL, obsSum;
        int row, col;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            row = i

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                col = j;

                updatedMatrix = reduce(matrix, row, col);
                obsSum = coordSearch(updatedMatrix, n- 1);
                if (obsSum < minSum)
                {
                    minSum = obsSum;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

For a 3x3 2d array, the recursive approach will look at the 9 coordinate pairs at the top level, then in the next level we will be dealing with a 2x2 2d array so we will only consider 4 coordinate pairs, then in the bottom level we just return whichever value resides in our 1x1 "2d array". Complexity is n^2 * (n-1)^2 * .. * 1. Keep in mind though, that each "step" requires updating the matrix which is a operation dense procedure.

Comment: With the recursive method , could you please say me how i can do that ?(with more details please)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion:  all of the sets of locations in the matrix that you want to use can be represented as permutations of an identity matrix whose "1" entries tell you which matrix elements to add up.  You then take the minimum over the set of sums for all of the permutations.  You can represent a permutation with a simple array since there are only N elements equal to 1 in a permutation of the NxN identity matrix.  So call that array p where p(i) tells you which column on the i'th row to use.

So the fundamental observation here is that you want all permutations of the NxN identity matrix, and you can represent these as permutations of (0,1,...,N-1).

Pseudocode might look like:

```
Given: an NxN matrix (2-D array), M, for which you want the minimal sum of N
       elements with no subset falling on the same row or column

minsum = N * max entry in M (just initialized to guarantee >= min sum sought)
foreach permutation p of (0,1,...,N-1):
   sum = 0
   for i = 0:N-1:
      sum += M(i,p(i))
      if sum >= minsum: break; # (if we already know this isn't a new min, move on)
   if sum < minsum: minsum = sum
print("minimum sum = ", minsum)
```

Adding a bit of code to remember a particular set of locations that add up to the minimum is left here as an exercise for the reader.  Note that this gives up on any permutation as soon as it's not going to be a new minimum sum.

For an NxN array, there are N! permutations, so in practice this gets expensive fast for large N (not your current problem at N = 5).  At that point, deeper dynamic programming techniques to quit early on partial results or avoid recomputing subset sums by using, say, memoization would be applicable and desirable.

Most other algorithms are going to do the same basic work in some way that may or may not look obviously similar in code.  I like this approach because it has a nice mapping onto a fairly straight-forward understanding in mathematical terms and you can readily identify that what makes it get expensive quickly as N grows is the need to calculate a minimum over a rapidly-expanding set of permutations.

Algorithms to compute all permutations of an array are pretty easy to come by and you get one for free in C++ in the function next_permutation, which is part of the STL.  My recommendation is to google "list all permutations" and if you need to work in a particular programming language, add that to the query as well.  The algorithm isn't terribly complicated and exists in both recursive and iterative forms.  And hey, for the 5x5 case you could probably statically list all 120 permutations anyway.